# new variables from untidy data based on suffix matching

Tags: r

I'd like to restructure my data frame, which features data on whether a home was viewed, purchased, or sold, and what the date for the viewing/purchase/sale was.

The data has been enterred in such a way that whilst there are multiple date variables (`var_datevar_A5_3_B32`,`var_datevar_A5_4_B33`,`var_datevar_A5_5_B34`), each of these variables contains a mix of sales-dates, purchase-dates, and viewing-dates.

So if a want to know if a date in eg `var_datevar_A5_3_B32` is a viewing, sales, or purchase date, I need to check variables with a matching prefix (A5_3_B32), ie  `var_viewed_A5_3_B32`, `var_sold_A5_3_B32`, and `var_purchased_A5_3_B32`, and see which one is coded as "Y".

I'd like to add three new variables to my data frame: a sales dates only variable (`var_date_sold`), a purchase dates only variable (`var_date_purchased`), and a viewing dates only variable (`var_date_viewed`), like in `dfgoal`.

I've made an attempt but apart from that I can't figure out how to paste the date into my new variable, I'd like a more general solution because in my real data set I've got loads of variables like this.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Starting point 
df <- data.frame(var_home=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                 var_datevar_A5_3_B32=c("01-12-2012","05-06-2014","03-09-2015","03-03-2016",NA),var_datevar_A5_4_B33=c("07-12-2012",NA,"07-07-2017","13-03-2016",NA),var_datevar_A5_5_B34=c("05-03-2013",NA,NA,"23-03-2016",NA),var_purchased_A5_3_B32=c(NA,"Y",NA,NA,NA),var_purchased_A5_4_B33=c("N","N","Y",NA,NA),var_purchased_A5_5_B34=c("Y",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 var_viewed_A5_3_B32=c("Y","N","Y","Y",NA),var_viewed_A5_4_B33=c(NA,NA,NA,"Y","N"),var_viewed_A5_5_B34=c(NA,NA,NA,"Y",NA),var_sold_A5_3_B32=c("NA","N",NA,"N",NA),var_sold_A5_4_B33=c("Y","N",NA,"N",NA),var_sold_A5_5_B34=c("N",NA,NA,NA,"Y"))



# Goal
dfgoal <- data.frame(var_home=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                 var_datevar_A5_3_B32=c("01-12-2012","05-06-2014","03-09-2015","03-03-2016",NA),var_datevar_A5_4_B33=c("07-12-2012",NA,"07-07-2017","13-03-2016",NA),var_datevar_A5_5_B34=c("05-03-2013",NA,NA,"23-03-2016",NA),var_purchased_A5_3_B32=c(NA,"Y",NA,NA,NA),var_purchased_A5_4_B33=c("N","N","Y",NA,NA),var_purchased_A5_5_B34=c("Y",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 var_viewed_A5_3_B32=c("Y","N","Y","Y",NA),var_viewed_A5_4_B33=c(NA,NA,NA,"Y","N"),var_viewed_A5_5_B34=c(NA,NA,NA,"Y",NA),var_sold_A5_3_B32=c("NA","N",NA,"N",NA),var_sold_A5_4_B33=c("Y","N",NA,"N",NA),var_sold_A5_5_B34=c("N",NA,NA,NA,"Y"),
                 var_date_viewed =c("01-12-2012",NA,"03-09-2015","03-03-2016,13-03-2016,23-03-2016",NA),var_date_sold=c("07-12-2012",NA,NA,NA,NA),var_date_purchased=c("05-03-2013","05-06-2014","07-07-2017",NA,NA))



# Attempt pseudo-code 
var_date_viewed <- ifelse((!is.na(var_datevar_A5_3_B32) & var_viewed_A5_3_B32=="Y") | (!is.na(var_datevar_A5_4_B33) & var_viewed_A5_4_B33=="Y") | (!is.na(var_datevar_A5_5_B34) & var_viewed_A5_5_B34=="Y"), PASTE_THE_DATE,NA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach using the packages `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  gather(datevar, date, contains("datevar")) %>%
  gather(action, action_yn, -datevar, -date, -var_home) %>%
  mutate(date_code = str_extract(datevar, "A\\d_\\d_B\\d\\d$"),
         action_code = str_extract(action, "A\\d_\\d_B\\d\\d$"), 
         action = str_extract(action, "^var_[[a-z][^_]]+"), 
         action = str_remove(action, "^var_")) %>% 
  filter(date_code == action_code) %>% 
  filter(action_yn == "Y") %>% 
  select(-datevar) %>% 
  group_by(var_home, action) %>% 
  summarise(date = str_c(date, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(action = str_c("var_date_", action)) %>% 
  spread(action, date)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   var_home [5]
#   var_home var_date_purchased var_date_sold var_date_viewed                 
#   <fct>    <chr>              <chr>         <chr>                           
# 1 a        05-03-2013         07-12-2012    01-12-2012                      
# 2 b        05-06-2014         NA            NA                              
# 3 c        07-07-2017         NA            03-09-2015                      
# 4 d        NA                 NA            03-03-2016,13-03-2016,23-03-2016
# 5 e        NA                 NA            NA
```

I'll split the code into several parts to explain, what is done.
First transform the data from wide to long format and first gather all `datvar` and then all actions together in one column each with the corresponding value (`date` and `action_yn`).

```
df <- df %>% 
  gather(datevar, date, contains("datevar")) %>%
  gather(action, action_yn, -datevar, -date, -var_home)

df
#     var_home              datevar       date                 action action_yn
# 1          a var_datevar_A5_3_B32 01-12-2012 var_purchased_A5_3_B32      <NA>
# 2          b var_datevar_A5_3_B32 05-06-2014 var_purchased_A5_3_B32         Y
# 3          c var_datevar_A5_3_B32 03-09-2015 var_purchased_A5_3_B32      <NA>
# 4          d var_datevar_A5_3_B32 03-03-2016 var_purchased_A5_3_B32      <NA>
# 5          e var_datevar_A5_3_B32       <NA> var_purchased_A5_3_B32      <NA>
# ...
```

Then extract the code (the last part of each column name) with a regular expression. Here I assume, that this is always structured like A#_#_B## where # is a number. Further the specific action is extracted again using a regular exxpression.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_code = str_extract(datevar, "A\\d_\\d_B\\d\\d$"),
         action_code = str_extract(action, "A\\d_\\d_B\\d\\d$"), 
         action = str_extract(action, "^var_[[a-z][^_]]+"), 
         action = str_remove(action, "^var_")) 

df
#     var_home              datevar       date    action action_yn date_code action_code
# 1          a var_datevar_A5_3_B32 01-12-2012 purchased      <NA>  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
# 2          b var_datevar_A5_3_B32 05-06-2014 purchased         Y  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
# 3          c var_datevar_A5_3_B32 03-09-2015 purchased      <NA>  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
# 4          d var_datevar_A5_3_B32 03-03-2016 purchased      <NA>  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
# 5          e var_datevar_A5_3_B32       <NA> purchased      <NA>  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
# ...
```

As we're only interested in the actions with "Y" and onlöy the dates corresponding to the right action we filter by de codes and action_yn. The `datevar` is not needed anymore and therefore dropped.

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(date_code == action_code) %>% 
  filter(action_yn == "Y") %>% 
  select(-datevar) 

df
#     var_home       date    action action_yn date_code action_code
#  1         b 05-06-2014 purchased         Y  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
#  2         c 07-07-2017 purchased         Y  A5_4_B33    A5_4_B33
#  3         a 05-03-2013 purchased         Y  A5_5_B34    A5_5_B34
#  4         a 01-12-2012    viewed         Y  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
#  5         c 03-09-2015    viewed         Y  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
#  6         d 03-03-2016    viewed         Y  A5_3_B32    A5_3_B32
#  7         d 13-03-2016    viewed         Y  A5_4_B33    A5_4_B33
#  8         d 23-03-2016    viewed         Y  A5_5_B34    A5_5_B34
#  9         a 07-12-2012      sold         Y  A5_4_B33    A5_4_B33
# 10         e       <NA>      sold         Y  A5_5_B34    A5_5_B34
```

Finally for each `var_home` and each `action`, the dates are pasted together (if there are several), the action is renamed (to get the desired final columnnames) and the each action is spread in its own column (with `spread`):

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(var_home, action) %>% 
  summarise(date = str_c(date, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(action = str_c("var_date_", action)) %>% 
  spread(action, date)
```

If you want to have this information together with the original data, assume this is stored in `df_org`. Then you can use `join`:

```
left_join(df_org, df, by = "var_home")
#   var_home var_datevar_A5_3_B32 var_datevar_A5_4_B33  ...  var_sold_A5_4_B33 var_sold_A5_5_B34 var_date_purchased var_date_sold var_date_viewed
# 1        a           01-12-2012           07-12-2012  ...  Y                 N                 05-03-2013         07-12-2012    01-12-2012
# 2        b           05-06-2014                 <NA>  ...  N                 <NA>              05-06-2014         <NA>          <NA>
# 3        c           03-09-2015           07-07-2017  ...  <NA>              <NA>              07-07-2017         <NA>          03-09-2015
# 4        d           03-03-2016           13-03-2016  ...  N                 <NA>              <NA>               <NA>          03-03-2016,13-03-2016,23-03-2016
# 5        e                 <NA>                 <NA>  ...  <NA>              Y                 <NA>               <NA>          <NA>
```